# Where is the speaker on the Yaesu FT-857D?

Tags: yaesu

I'm considering buying a Yaesu FT-857D for car mount and I'm now concerned the speaker is on the body and only the body and not on the head unit.

Where's the speaker? Can a mic contain the speaker too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have one handy to validate this, but [in the manual](https://www.yaesu.com/downloadFile.cfm?FileID=12848&FileCatID=158&FileName=FT%2D857D%5FOM%5FENG%5FEH007M108.pdf&FileContentType=application%2Fpdf) you can see the speaker grille on top of the radio in the angled view on page 20. This is the same place it is on my FT-897. So, yes, the speaker is on the body.

The microphone connector pinout is unfortunately not described in the manual (it is in the FT-897's, which is largely identical), but it does not contain audio output, so no speaker-mic can be connected.

However, **you can connect an external speaker to the EXT SPKR 3.5mm mono jack,** described on pages 34-35. You will have to mount it separately, but communications speakers with suitable mounting brackets and cables are a common item (if often expensive for the sound quality you get).

Comment: Yeah, I took a look at the manual and I could see a speaker on the body, but I couldn't confirm the lack of speaker on the head or mic. Thank you.